# Is there any way of calling Angularjs directive with data

Tags: angularjs

Assuming I have JSON that defines a bunch of stuff, including the name of a directive is it possible to call that directive dynamically in my html?

```
inputs = [{type:'t',directive:'my-input-plain'},{type:'n1',directive:'my-input-moneyone'}];
```

Then in the HTML
    
        <{{input.directive}}>

My fall back is a long ng-switch which in the long run may be easier to debug.

Comment: You can create a directive that adds your directive dynamicly to html and compiles it.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have an example plunked around?

Comment: Have jsfiddle,  http://jsfiddle.net/michal_taborowski/mmd2c5gf/ - it is simple example, but you should get it, if more explanation needed just write.